# Force project to use Yarn but not npm

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

As a team practice, I would like to force my teammate to use `yarn install/ run` but not `npm install/ run`.

Is it possible to force a `package.json` 's dependency be installed only via `yarn install` or `package.json`'s script be run only via `yarn run`?

If it cannot be done, can I at least get a warning when using `npm install`?

---

Again, this is only to align the team practice, so that reduces the possibility of error/ problem produced during dev/ops. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One of the way I can think of is CI can set a rules to detect if there is new file `package-lock.json` file being created, make the build fail. The developer will then realized he made a mistake since his build failed.

Alternatively you can also rely on [husky pre-commit hook](https://github.com/typicode/husky), which essentially runs a command to check if `package-lock.json` existed everytime developer trying to run `git commit`.